# Is best practice to discharge sump through cinder blocks closer to ground, or through wood plate higher above ground?

Tags: joists, exterior, cinderblock, utilities

I have a sump pump that needs to discharge outside. Next to the sump is maybe 9ft of cinder blocks for the basement wall, but in this side of the basement, ground-level is just 4ft higher elevation than the sump.

In a situation like this, is it better (code compliant, more reliable, more efficient) to...

1. run the pump's drain higher up the wall to exit out the wood
   joist that sits above the cinder-blocks, discharging maybe 5ft above
   ground level outside the house, or
2. run the pump's drain just a foot or two above ground level,
   cutting a hole through the basement cinder-block wall and sealing it
   with water plug cement or caulking?

I think of wood as much better to put holes in, both for ease of install and also for repair if needed in the future. For example I imagine sistering more wood to a joist is much easier than plugging a hole in a house's cinder block foundation. That said I am not an expert, so I am asking, which option is more in line with best practices in the U.S.? If it varies, what are key considerations/variables that would lead to one option being a standard choice over the other in different situations?

Comment: How high the sump pump can push the water up is the main thing.  9 feet is getting near the top end.  A local tool rental place should have a nice hole saw to make quick work.  Will want to have pipe to carry the water away from the house.

Comment: @crip659 it is a 1/3hp pump and I think could do the job. Aside from different in work to cut through wood vs cinder block, is there any reason to prefer going through one material vs the other (like ease of repair)?

Comment: About the only thing will be length of pipe outside.  Want the water away from the house, but other than that, will just depend on the tools you have/rent.

Comment: @crip659 Okay, good to know. In that case, going with the lower exit through the wall seems better to reduce splash and make it a shorter connection to a hose line or trenches on the ground outside.

Comment: There shouldn't be any "splash" from the water, no matter which method you use. The output should continue to run in a hose/discharge pipe some distance from the house to _prevent_ splash damage and to actually carry the water far enough away that it's not going to just drain right back inside. The one advantage I see to going higher is that there is some extra momentum to carry the water further away if your land is pretty flat.